# Execute typescript functions called from executeScript from InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, ionic3, inappbrowser

I am implementing ionic cordova InAppBrowser functionality, in which I have to call a function written outside the InAppBrowser "loadstop" event.
What I want here is to call a callBack() function soon after executing loadstop event.

My dummy code is:

```
this.browser.on("loadstop").subscribe((event)=>{
this.browser.executeScript({code: if(document.getElementByID("ID").length > 1){function callBack();}})
});

callback(){
this.browser.hide();
}
```

Comment: Is your intention that `callBack()` would call a Typescript function inside your Cordova app?

Comment: Yes I want to call that callback() having typescript call when the given condition fulfill in the cordova app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `code` you inject via `executeScript()` is executed in the scope of the InappBrowser Webview, not the Cordova app Webview, so has no visibility of functions in your Cordova app.
Also note that the `code` argument passed to `executeScript()` must be stringified Javascript because it will be passed to the InappBrowser Webview via the native bridge.

Therefore there are 2 ways you can achieve your callback:

Firstly, because the condition whether to invoke your callback can be evaluated synchronously in the context of the InappBrowser Webview, you can synchronously return the result of your DOM query using current npm releases of `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`, for example:

```
callBack(){
    console.log("Typescript callback has been called");
    this.browser.hide();
}

this.browser.on("loadstop").subscribe((event)=>{
    this.browser.executeScript(
        {
            code: 'document.getElementByID("ID").length > 1;'
        },
        function(values){
            var result = values[0];
            if(result){
                callBack();
            }
        }
    );
});
```

However if the result of your condition needed to be returned asynchronously, the above method would not work.
Instead you could use the postMessage API implementation, added to `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` for Android & iOS platforms by [this PR](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/362).
It's not yet been released in a version to npm, so you'd need to install the master branch of the plugin directly from the Github repo:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

You'd then use it like this:

```
callBack(){
    console.log("Typescript callback has been called");
    this.browser.hide();
}

this.browser.on("message").subscribe((event)=>{
    if(event.data.action === "callBack"){
        callBack();
    }
});

this.browser.on("loadstop").subscribe((event)=>{
    this.browser.executeScript(
        {
            code: '\
                setTimeout(function(){\
                    if(document.getElementByID("ID").length > 1){\
                        webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab.postMessage(JSON.stringify({\
                            action: "callBack"\
                        }));\
                    } \
                }, 250);\
            '
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: I have tried the asynchronous way, it gives following error:

 Uncaught ReferenceError: webkit is not defined,

did you receive this error?

Comment: @harsh see [this test project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-test) for a working example. Also see [this comment](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/issues/472#issuecomment-491786494).